Page x of y /rfoot
Using the following command I get a weird font in italic for page number "x/y". How do I get it to say "Page x of y" in regular font?
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{Name}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\lftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt}

\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{2pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}


Please add a compilable [mre]

Try with \textrm{Page ...}. However, more detail is necessary to provide an adequate answer.

Where do you recommend adding this line? If you need any details, please let me know.
